# How to keep track (write, read, update) of element states via localStorage?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, local-storage, state

first of all, I apologize that I don't speak English, I am trying to improve in this language.

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve it, I have a web in WordPress and it creates buttons dynamically with some dynamic classes, I need to take 1 of those classes to do the following:

Let's imagine that we have 5 buttons, when I clicked on 1 of those 5 that the other 4 buttons are hidden and this is saved in the local storage, ie everything is kept in the browser.

I have this code:

```
 $('.dce-button').click(function(event){
      $(this).attr('data-id' , 'Next');
      localStorage.setItem("class", "noDisplay");
      localStorage.setItem("noDisplay", "true");
      $('.dce-button').not(this).each(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass("noDisplay");
      });
})
```

I use it to select the button I need and WORKS, it disappears the other 4 but I don't know how to keep it with the local storage, Is someone can help me?

Comment: Once the OP has managed to solve writing to and reading from the local storage the proper button state there will be never a chance of any other button visible than the very one which was selected at the very first time (unless one resets/erases the local storage's state(s)).

Comment: Try saving the `id` of the currently clicked button in local storage. If they don't have `id` attributes you might be able to use their index in a collection or nodelist of buttons  - or just give them `id`s.  On page load access the button by its stored id and click it in script.

Comment: No, thanks to all the comments I was able to solve my problem, thank you very much!

Comment: @JeyMhinHo ... The OP then might consider accepting the answer which was most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work and address Peter's comment

(working JS fiddle since localStorage isnt accessible in snippets on SO https://jsfiddle.net/f7804xwc/1/)

```js
  // on page load, get the stored value if there is one and set the buttons accordingly
  let selectedBtn = localStorage.getItem('selectedBtn');
  if (selectedBtn) {
    $('.dce-button').hide();
    $('#'+selectedBtn).show()
  }


  $('.dce-button').click(function(event) {
    let selectedBtn = localStorage.getItem('selectedBtn');
    console.log(selectedBtn);
    if (selectedBtn === this.id) {
      // user clicked the selected button again, lets un-select it and re-show all the buttons
      localStorage.removeItem('selectedBtn');
      $('.dce-button').show();

    } else {
      // user clicked a button, store selection and hide the others
      localStorage.setItem("selectedBtn", this.id);
      $('.dce-button').not(this).each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="dce-button" id="btn1">Button 1</button><br>
<button class="dce-button" id="btn2">Button 2</button><br>
<button class="dce-button" id="btn3">Button 3</button><br>
<button class="dce-button" id="btn4">Button 4</button><br>
<button class="dce-button" id="btn5">Button 5</button><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment ...

> *"Once the OP has managed to solve writing to and reading from the local storage the proper button state there will be never a chance of any other button visible than the very one which was selected at the very first time (unless one resets/erases the local storage's state(s))."*

... and all code of the next provided example which relates to `initStorageRelatedUIHandling` (the last 3 buttons which are for logging, clearing and rendering from the local storage's current state) is going to prove the above said/commented.

Now as for a possible solution, I personally would chose an approach which stores the state(s) of any **DCE** related button as a [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) 'ed array. Thus one does not rely on any specific button identification but stays generic from the beginning based on just a list of queried (jquery or selector api ... it doesn't matter) DOM nodes.

One would write 2 functions `writeDceState` and `readDceState` which both take care of the storage and JSON handling.

Another function like `updateDceState` exclusively takes care of generating the current array representation of any buttons state based on the currently targeted/selected button. It queries a list of all DCE buttons and does map each visibility state as `false` except for the currently chosen. It finally forwards the updated state to `writeDceState`.

The render part is covered exclusively by `renderDceStateFromStorage`. It reads the most current state from storage and updates each button's visibility from the parsed array.

Then there is a sole handler function ... `handleDceStateChange` ... which on `click` invokes both functions one after the other ...   `updateDceState` and `renderDceStateFromStorage`.

```js
function writeDceState(state = null) {
  // `mock` is a specifc namespace which carries
  // `localStorage` behavior for SO environments.
  // - Thus the next line can be omitted later.
  const { localStorage } = mock;

  localStorage
    .setItem('dce', JSON.stringify(state)
  );
}
function readDceState() {
  // `mock` is a specifc namespace which carries
  // `localStorage` behavior for SO environments.
  // - Thus the next line can be omitted later.
  const { localStorage } = mock;

  return JSON
    .parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dce') || null
    );
}

function updateDceState(dceTarget) {
  const state = Array
    .from(
      document
        .querySelectorAll('.dce-button')
    )
    .map(elm => (elm === dceTarget));

  writeDceState(state);
}
function renderDceStateFromStorage() {
  const state = readDceState();
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.dce-button')
    .forEach((elm, idx) =>
      elm.disabled = !!state && !state[idx]
    );
}

function handleDceStateChange({ currentTarget }) {
  updateDceState(currentTarget);
  renderDceStateFromStorage();
}

function initDceHandling() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.dce-button')
    .forEach(elm =>
      elm.addEventListener('click', handleDceStateChange)
    );
}
function initStorageRelatedUIHandling() {
  document
    .querySelector('[data-state-display]')
    .addEventListener('click', () =>
      console.log( readDceState() )
    );
  document
    .querySelector('[data-state-clear]')
    .addEventListener('click', mock.localStorage.clear);

  document
    .querySelector('[data-state-rerender]')
    .addEventListener('click', renderDceStateFromStorage);
}

initDceHandling();
initStorageRelatedUIHandling();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
li:nth-child(6) { margin-top: 20px; }
li:nth-child(8) { margin-top: 10px; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="dce-button">Foo</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="dce-button">Bar</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="dce-button">Baz</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="dce-button">Biz</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="dce-button">Buzz</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button data-state-clear>clear storage state</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button data-state-display>display storage state</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button data-state-rerender>rerender from storage</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  // mock for the SO specific stack snippet
  // due to the policies and environment are
  // not allowing an original storage access.
  const mock = {
    localStorage: (function () {

      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
      const storage = new Map;

      function key(int) {
        return [
          ...storage.keys()
        ][parseInt(int, 10)];
      }

      function setItem(key, value) {
        return storage.set(String(key), String(value));
      }
      function getItem(key) {
        return storage.get(String(key));
      }

      function removeItem(key) {
        return storage.delete(String(key));
      }

      function clear() {
        return storage.clear();
      }

      return {
        get length() {
          return storage.size;
        },
        key,
        getItem,
        setItem,
        removeItem,
        clear,      
      };

    }()),
  }
</script>
```